# How to nest MySQL results into a JSON array using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Please see the link below...
http://api.androiddeft.com/cities/cities_array.json

I'm trying to nest my results from the DB into the structure below:

```
[
    {
        region:"1",
        province:[{
           "Ilocos Norte",
           "Ilocos Sur"  
         }]
    },
    {
        region:"2",
        province:[{
           "Isabela",
           "Cagayan"  
         }]
    }
]
```

However what I have tried isn't working, I'm not able to get the results I am looking for:

```
$rows = array();
$rs = array();
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT regDesc, regCode FROM refregion ORDER BY regCode ASC");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT provDesc FROM refprovince WHERE regCode = '".$row["regCode"]."' ORDER BY provCode ASC");      

    while($rs=mysqli_fetch_array($result2))

    $rows[] = array(
        'region' => $row["regDesc"],
        'province'=>$rs["provDesc"]
        );
    }           

echo json_encode($rows);
```

This instead results in the following output:

```
[
  {
    region: "REGION I",
    province: "ILOCOS NORTE"
  },
  {
    region: "REGION I",
    province: "ILOCOS SUR"
  },
  {
    region: "REGION II",
    province: "CAGAYAN"
  },
  {
    region: "REGION II",
    province: "ISABELA"
  }
```

]

Comment: you forgot?, okay i'll refresh your memory again, get the json using `file_get_contents`, then `json_decode` it (with the `true` flag), then treat it like any normal array, add as many as you wish. you have to do the coding though.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. It's also unclear what code you have, and what fixes you attempted so far.

Comment: I found the answer here...
thanks to your answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34668484/creating-array-inside-array-from-mysql-data-to-json

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    $rows = array();
    $rs = array();
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT regDesc, regCode FROM refregion ORDER BY regCode ASC");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $region = $row['regDesc'];
        $result2 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT provDesc FROM refprovince WHERE regCode = '".$row["regCode"]."' ORDER BY provCode ASC");      

        while($rs=mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
            array_push($province,$rs['provDesc'];
        }           

        $tempArray = array(
            'region' => $region,
            'province' => $province
        )

        array_push($rows,$tempArray);
    }

    echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: From review: could you please add some more explanation to your answer?